# ECMAScript Global Execution Context Creation

Tags: javascript

In the following code snippet, when viewing the call stack in chrome dev tools, it shows `(anonymous)` which is the global execution context.

```js
debugger
setTimeout(() => {
  console.log('foo')
}, 3000)
```

When this runs the call stack shows:

```
(anonymous)
```

If the code is stepped through, then the code gets paused again after 3 seconds and the call stack shows:

```
(anonymous)
setTimeout(async)
(anonymous) // is this a brand new global execution context?
```

**Is the first stack frame the same global execution context as the first stack frame in the second snippet when the callback is invoked?**

I am assuming that the browser is the host environment and after the code finishes execution the call stack is empty, then the browser must create a global execution context all over again *and* add the anonymous function to the call stack. In other words the original global execution context is not preserved.

Here the [spec](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-jobs) talks about callbacks and says:

> At some future point in time, when there is no running context in the agent for which the job is scheduled and that agent's execution context stack is empty, the implementation must:
> Perform any host-defined preparation steps.
> Invoke the Job Abstract Closure.
> Perform any host-defined cleanup steps, after which the execution context stack must be empty.

It also states:

> At any particular time, scriptOrModule (a Script Record, a Module Record, or null) is the active script or module if all of the following conditions are true:
>
> - GetActiveScriptOrModule() is scriptOrModule.
> - If scriptOrModule is a Script Record or Module Record, let ec be the topmost execution context on the execution context stack whose ScriptOrModule component is scriptOrModule. The Realm component of ec is scriptOrModule.[[Realm]].

It appears the browser goes through these [steps](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-initializehostdefinedrealm) when the call stack is empty

> 9.6 InitializeHostDefinedRealm ( )
>
> The abstract operation InitializeHostDefinedRealm takes no arguments and returns either a normal completion containing unused or a throw completion. It performs the following steps when called:
>
> 1. Let realm be CreateRealm().
> 2. Let newContext be a new execution context.
> 3. Set the Function of newContext to null.
> 4. Set the Realm of newContext to realm.
> 5. Set the ScriptOrModule of newContext to null.
> 6. Push newContext onto the execution context stack; newContext is now the running execution context.
> 7. If the host requires use of an exotic object to serve as realm's global object, let global be such an object created in a host-defined manner. Otherwise, let global be undefined, indicating that an ordinary object should be created as the global object.
> 8. If the host requires that the this binding in realm's global scope return an object other than the global object, let thisValue be such an object created in a host-defined manner. Otherwise, let thisValue be undefined, indicating that realm's global this binding should be the global object.
> 9. Perform SetRealmGlobalObject(realm, global, thisValue).
> 10. Let globalObj be ? SetDefaultGlobalBindings(realm).
> 11. Create any host-defined global object properties on globalObj.
> 12. Return unused.

The other thing I am not completely sure about is how the execution context is created, I am assuming that for a callback, the abstract operation `InitializeHostDefinedRealm( )` is used for creating a global execution context for a callback if the call stack is empty, and if not it seems [ScriptEvaluation](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-runtime-semantics-scriptevaluation) is called internally.

Take a look below at step 9, **why does the running execution context need to be suspended, is the ScriptEvaluation() operation not creating a global execution context?**

It looks like the whole point of this abstract operation is indeed to create a global execution context yet it has a step to suspend the current execution context.

`Script Evaluation` has the following steps

> 1. Let globalEnv be scriptRecord.[[Realm]].[[GlobalEnv]].
> 2. Let scriptContext be a new ECMAScript code execution context.
> 3. Set the Function of scriptContext to null.
> 4. Set the Realm of scriptContext to scriptRecord.[[Realm]].
> 5. Set the ScriptOrModule of scriptContext to scriptRecord.
> 6. Set the VariableEnvironment of scriptContext to globalEnv.
> 7. Set the LexicalEnvironment of scriptContext to globalEnv.
> 8. Set the PrivateEnvironment of scriptContext to null.
> 9. Suspend the running execution context.
> 10. Push scriptContext onto the execution context stack; scriptContext is now the running execution context.
> 11. Let script be scriptRecord.[[ECMAScriptCode]].
> 12. Let result be Completion(GlobalDeclarationInstantiation(script, globalEnv)).
> 13. If result.[[Type]] is normal, then
>
> - Set result to Completion(Evaluation of script).
> - If result.[[Type]] is normal and result.[[Value]] is empty, then
> - Set result to NormalCompletion(undefined).
>
> 14. Suspend scriptContext and remove it from the execution context stack.
> 15. Assert: The execution context stack is not empty.
> 16. Resume the context that is now on the top of the execution context stack as the running execution context.
> 17. Return ? result.

Comment: In the browser, the global execution context is created when the page is loaded. It persists until the page is unloaded. When the top-level JS finishes, it continues running in that context to process asynchronous events.

Comment: So it doesn't go away when the call stack is empty -- you would lose all your global variables if that happened.

Comment: Why on Step 9 of script evaluation does it state that the running execution context needs to be suspended? The spec words it as the script evaluation operation sets up the global execution context.

Comment: Much of the EcmaScript spec is inscrutible to me.

Comment: @Barmar Don't confuse the global execution context with the realm and its global environment. The former only provides the bottom stack frame, and may be reused or get recreated during every script evaluation, whereas the latter holds the global variables.

Comment: Re "*Is the first stack frame the same global execution context as the first stack frame in the second snippet when the callback is invoked?*" - yes. Notice the `setTimeout(async)`, which is an [async stack trace](https://developer.chrome.com/blog/async-call-stack/), so it indeed refers to where the `setTimeout` was called in the first execution

Comment: @Bergi I have one question still, on [step 9 of Script Evaluation](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-runtime-semantics-scriptevaluation) it says the running execution context is suspended, is this not the global execution context, and InitializeHostDefinedRealm ( ) seems like it is a global execution context, what is the difference? [Script Evaluation](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-runtime-semantics-scriptevaluation) and [InitializeHostDefinedRealm()](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-initializehostdefinedrealm) are the only instances in the spec I found that create an execution context for global code.

Comment: @Bergi I just noticed that an *execution context* is created in `9.6 InitializeHostDefinedRealm(` and in `16.1.6 ScriptEvaluation` an *ECMAScript execution context* is created. An *ECMAScript execution context* seems to be a subclass of execution context which has additional state components, ie. lexical environment. Am I right in assuming that any time global code is evaluated a global execution context is created and pushed on top of an *execution context* from *InitializeHostDefinedRealm*? When global code finishes, is the execution context from *InitializeHostDefinedRealm also popped?

Comment: @dbzx10299 tbh I have no idea what this extra execution context is used for. The [section on jobs](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-jobs) says "*At any particular time, an execution is prepared to evaluate ECMAScript code if […] the execution context stack is not empty. […] Host environments may prepare an execution to evaluate code by pushing execution contexts onto the execution context stack. The specific steps are implementation-defined. […] This initial execution context […] is only in use before any callback function is invoked.*"

Comment: Maybe this is useful if some of the implementation-defined steps in *InitializeHostDefinedRealm* do their setup by calling other things from the spec that presume a running execution context. Also it might be related to top-level await and the [module execution](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-source-text-module-record-execute-module). But afaics, the execution context created in *InitializeHostDefinedRealm* is not used for anything else other than as such a first execution context that prepares the host to evaluate code - regardless whether that's a module, a script, or something else.

Comment: [Script Evaluation](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-runtime-semantics-scriptevaluation) step 9 says the running execution context should be suspended, which is indeed this extra execution context and on line 16 this original execution context is resumed as the running execution context after the global execution context is popped off of the call stack. The [jobs](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-jobs) section says that 'when there is no running context ...' so I assume that original execution context must be popped as well.

Comment: And here in the execution context section, where it says [ScriptOrModule](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#running-execution-context) it says: 'The Module Record or Script Record from which associated code originates. If there is no originating script or module, as is the case for the original execution context created in InitializeHostDefinedRealm, the value is null'. In chrome dev tools this will not be visible as it seems to be some internal spec related construct

Comment: Yes, exactly. Notice that neither *InitializeHostDefinedRealm* nor *ScriptEvaluation* are called from any other operation in the ECMAScript spec, they provide the entry points to call for other specs (e.g. web standards) or just the custom scripting environment. "*this will not be visible as it seems to be some internal spec related construct*" - yes, absolutely, see the [section on execution contexts](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-execution-contexts): "*An execution context is purely a specification mechanism and need not correspond to any particular artefact of an ECMAScript implementation.*"